# 13.10 graphics tablet recognized but not working

Tags: drivers, 13.10, tablet, wacom

i'm using genius i608x tablet and in 13.10 it is recognized by name with lsusb also gimp recognizes the tablet but the mouse pointer is not moving. I can click on stuff so I guess the buttons are working but I can't move the cursor.

I'm looking for solutions since ever, there were some wizardpen drivers with support for these tablets but it's old.

To be able to use ubuntu for something more than browsing internet I need my space navigator and tablet. 3dconnexion is working fine but I have no clue on how to make the tablet work.

Comment: Somehow it started moving (I have no idea why) But now the cursor is moving but buttons act weird. If I click let's say in browser it actually loads previous page..

Comment: Is there a way to map the buttons of tablet to funcions in ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: xinput query state shows all my keys and buttons of tablet to be mapped as "up"...

Comment: xinput-query-state shows 3 classes and if i try to use set-button-map command to map buttons it doesn't do anything.. do i need to also point out via command somehow that i want to change mapping in specific class and how?

Comment: alright for someone with this problem |xinput set-button-map [device ID or name in 'quotes'] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 | solved button mapping so button number 8 is left click and next two are other pen buttons rest of them i don't know why there are 14 listed.. ANYWAYS i still haven't figured out how should i set pressure sensitivity for this.. i guess it won't be this easy, any help??

Comment: the xinput test is showing me only two axes and when i press on pen it's only recognized as button press 1 and button release 1..